# What are the differences between > and space?

Tags: css

What are the differences between these two styles :

```
element1 > element2 {
   ...
}
```

and

```
element1 element2 {
   ...
}
```

Comment: > - is direct child

Comment: A space select all descendants while `>` selects only children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element1 > element2` selects all `<element2>` elements where the parent is a `<element1>` element (see [child combinator selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) for more information) while `element1 element2` selects all `<element2>` elements inside `<element1>` elements (see [descendant selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) for more information).

**Example:**
If you have to following DOM markup (see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58oru7c8/3/)):

```
a
  c
  b
    c
  d
    c
```

And you use `a c {bg -> red}` (pseudo-code) all c elements will turn red, but if you also use `a > c {bg -> blue}` the first c element will turn blue while the other will be red. This is because the a element is the direct parent of the first c element.

Answer (score 3):

`element1 element2` selects all elements inside `element1`

**Example**

```html
<style>
.element1 .element2{ 
    color: #2196F3;
    background-color: #FFEB3B;
}
</style>

<div class="element1">
    <p class="element2">
        As you can see that this paragraph with class `element2` is inside div with class `element1` and so it's catched by css written above.
    </p>
</div>
```

Whereas

`element1 > element2` selects every `element2` where the parent is a `element1`

```html
<style>
.element1 > .element2{ 
    color: #2196F3;
    background-color: #FFEB3B;
}
</style>

<div class="element1">
    <p class="element2">
        This paragraph is catched by css above because this paragraph with class `element2` is immediate child of div with class `element1`.
    </p>
</div>

<!--no effect-->
<div class="element1">
   <div class="middleelement">
      <p class="element2">
          This paragraph is <strong>NOT</strong> catched by css written above because it's not immediate child of div with class `element1` because class `middleelement` comes in between. To refer to this paragraph, you have to write css as `.element1 &gt; .middleelement &gt; .element2`
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`>` is the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) which signifies a direct child while a space (or `>>`) is the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors), meaning the other element can be anywhere inside the first one.

If you have the following DOM tree

```
a
  b
    c
  d
```

then `a > c` will match nothing, while `a c` will match the `c` element.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> element1 element2
> ```

Selects all `elements` inside `elements`

> ```
> element1 > element2
> ```

Selects all `elements` where the parent is a `element`